# Microsoft CRM 4.0 LINQ - Getting attribute displaynames from CRM with LINQ

Tags: xml, linq, dynamics-crm-4

Has anyone done this with the Xrm Advanced Dev Extension? I am creating an external portal

Let's say I have an attribute in the account entity called aaa_accountfield. The account entity XML has

```
<displaynames>
 <displayname description="attribute display name" languagecode="1033" />
 <displayname description="attribute display name in some other language" languagecode="1045" />
</displaynames>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what it has to do with XML but I'm pretty sure you can use the ADX to get an IOrganizationService which should be able to make metadata requests.  I would give the following code a shot.  You should probably modify it to check whether the different languages return values before grabbing the first or you will be susceptible to exceptions.

```
 var crm = new Xrm.XrmDataContext("CacheDisabled");
 crm.UsingService(service =>
        {
                // Use this code to grab a complete set of EntityMetadata.
                var entityRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest();
                entityRequest.LogicalName = "account";
                entityRequest.RetrieveAsIfPublished = false;

                RetrieveEntityResponse entityResponse = new RetrieveEntityResponse();
                EntityMetadata entityMetadata = entityResponse.EntityMetadata;
                //entityMetadata.Attributes...

                // Use this to grab AttributeMetadata for a specific attribute.
                RetrieveAttributeRequest attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
                attributeRequest.EntityLogicalName = "account";
                attributeRequest.LogicalName = "name";
                attributeRequest.RetrieveAsIfPublished = false;

                RetrieveAttributeResponse attributeResponse = new RetrieveAttributeResponse();
                AttributeMetadata attributeMetadata = attributeResponse.AttributeMetadata;
                string labelLanguage1 = attributeMetadata.DisplayName.LocLabels.Where(l => l.LanguageCode.Value == 1033).First().Label;
                string labelLanguage2 = attributeMetadata.DisplayName.LocLabels.Where(l => l.LanguageCode.Value == 1045).First().Label;

        }
```

Comment: I just realized this is CRM 2011. Got any idea for CRM 4.0?

Comment: Never mind I got it - Thanks anyway :) I'm good for 2011 then when we upgrade

Comment: Nope, this is CRM 4.0 code with the CRM SDK version 4.0.12 addition of the advanced developer extensions.  CRM 2011 code is similiar to this.  I figured that since you mentioned "Advanced developer extensions" in the title, you must be talking about this..